# An internal error occurred during: “Computing SDK Info…” When Starting Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Since upgrading TitaniumStudio, I am getting a java error when starting the TitaniumStudio application. Full error message is:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Computing SDK Info...".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I try to create a new project, I get

```
Unable to locate the CLI executable. Please restart Studio or use Help > Check for Titanium Updates to install Titanium CLI.
```

I have no idea how to bypass this error. I tried installing and reinstalling the application, installing and reinstalling CLI via command line with no luck.

I am running osx with Yosemite.

```
Titanium 3.4.1
Node v0.10.33
npm 1.4.28
```

Any suggestion on where else to look in order to solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: are you able to run titanium commands from terminal? ( [also see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965858/titanium-sdk-will-not-recognize-titanium-cli-node-alloy-or-npm-on-ubuntu-12-0) )

Comment: @turtle thanks a lot. I discovered that link you posted yesterday and was able to solve my problem with that, installing everything within titanium. It looks there was an issue with the environmental variables and when I was opening titanium it was considered a new session for the systems and variables where not there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I switched from using node 0.12 to 0.10.13.  Here are the two commands:
    **npm install -g n**
    
    **n 0.10.13**

then restart titanium studio

Comment: After running this I still has the error "Computing SDK Info...", however I was now able to install the Titanium updates which failed prior.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering this 3 months after the question was asked, but the solution provided by @turtle above didn't work for me.

I was getting the exact same error with a brand new install of Titanium (SDK 3.5) on OS X 10.10.2 and the latest version (0.12) of Node already installed. This happened on 3 separate Macs. I compared with a 4th Mac that already had Titanium installed and found out that reverting Node from 0.12 to 0.10.13 made the error go away, solved the problem on all 3 Macs!

Answer (score 0):

Do a complete reinstall of titanium studio git and noe.It will solve your problem.

Comment: this can go as comment